# updating ActionBar status from OnCancelled method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an a refresh button in `ActionBar` that refreshes the current activity when Clicked. This button is activated only when `AysncTask` is callcelled

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.desc_xml, menu);

        refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        return true;
    }
```

`onPrepareOptionsMenu` method, I set it to `false`

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    refreshItem.setEnabled(false);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);       
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_refresh:
            new AsycnTaskName(MyClass.this).execute();
            break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and inside `onCancelled` method of `AsyncTask`, I re-enabled it.

```
@Override
        protected void onCancelled(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            refreshItem.setEnabled(true)
        }
```

but the status of the refresh button stays disable even after `onCancelled` method is executed.

What Am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` it calls `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` again.

Your problem is, you are setting `refreshItem.setEnabled(false)` each time while preparing option menu. So this menu does not get activated even if you set it to `true`.

*So you need to take one global variable at class level and set it to `false` by default. And then handle this variable only.*

Like below

```
private boolean refreshItemEnabled = false; // At class level
```

.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    refreshItem.setEnabled(refreshItemEnabled); // Set variable here, not hardcoded value
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);       
    return true;
}
```

and then your `onCancelled()` will be like

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(c, "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    refreshItemEnabled = true; // Set menu enabled
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: @Joe Updated the answer. Check that.

Comment: i answered the same, but +1 to you for explanation (y).

Answer (score 0):

declare a `static boolean` variable in your main activity class.

```
static boolean setStatus = false;
```

in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`,

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    refreshItem.setEnabled(YourClassName.setStatus);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);       
    return true;
}
```

update that variable in your `OnCancelled` method,

```
    YourClassName.setStatus = true;
    refreshItem.setEnabled(YourClassName.setStatus)
```

You can also set your button to invisible when it is inactive,

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    refreshItem.setEnabled(YourClassName.setStatus);
    refreshItem.setVisible(YourClassName.setStatus);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);       
    return true;
}
```